# win - python 2.7 & 3.6 - switching version that script uses from shell

Tags: windows, windows-10, shell, python, environment-variables

I have placed a script `test.py` in my `%USERPROFILE%` folder:

```
import sys
print("TEST", sys.version_info, sys.executable)
```

When running `cmd` (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and then typing `test`+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> the following is returned:

```
C:\Users\wittrup>test
('TEST', sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0), 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe')
```

I would like this to run with python 3.6.

There are two python versions installed:

- `C:\Python27\python.exe`
- `C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3`

`echo %path:;=&echo.%` shows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.5.1-4
C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console
C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

(and a bunch of other stuff I deemed irrelevant for this case)

```
C:\Users\wittrup>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
```

Registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe
C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\python.exe
C:\Users\wittrup\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

What beats me here, is I really cannot figure out how Windows ends up running the script with python 2.6 - any other places to look?

```
C:\Users\wittrup>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]
```

Comment: Add to the post the output of `assoc .py` and  `ftype | findstr py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve by question-comment (thanks!).

```
; Note the detail about administrator privileges
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ASSOC .py
.py=Python.File

C:\WINDOWS\system32>FTYPE | FINDSTR Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

C:\WINDOWS\system32>FTYPE /?
Displays or modifies file types used in file extension associations

FTYPE [fileType[=[openCommandString]]]

  fileType  Specifies the file type to examine or change
  openCommandString Specifies the open command to use when launching files
                    of this type.
; more ...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>FTYPE Python.File="python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="python.exe" "%1" %*
```

And I'll let environment variables handle the rest.